# how to optimizize SSAS cube

Tags: ssas

i have read various article discussing different methods to optimize the SSAS Cube processing time but each one of them takes much time than i expected.

**Background**

I have a couple of tables in database that undergoes transaction 24/7, i have created a view and populate my cube and dimension with that view. i have only one cube that has only one measure and only one dimension.
Initially i have "Process Full" my dimension and cube respectively (it takes almost an hour). Now i want to update the cube once in every hour to reflect the current statistics.

**Question**

Now what type of "Process Option" do i need to consider to process the cube quickly?

**What i have tried so far**

***Process Default***:when i do "Process Default" to both dimension and cube, it takes less then a minute to succeed but reflects no recent changes.

***Process Update*** : when i do "Process Update" to both dimension and cube ,it takes every time(once in every hour) almost an hour to succeed to reflects recent changes.

***Process Full*** : when i do "Process Full" to both dimension and cube (), it takes every time(once in every hour) almost an hour to succeed to reflects recent changes.

***Process Incremental***: This option only add the new records but do not reflect any update or delete to the previous records present in the cube.

kindly give me any tip to resolve the matter.

Comment: What version of SSAS? Have you read the [SSAS performance guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karang/archive/2014/05/28/analysis-services-molap-performance-guide-for-sql-server-2012-and-2014.aspx)?

Comment: I am using SSAS 2008 R2. Yes i have read almost all the guide for performance boost.